# devops Static web app Release task does not create preview environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure Static webapp running and a pipeline building PR builds. In the release task you can state the production branch, and all other branches should be released as preview environments.

From helptext: "Production branch. When specified and Deployment Environment is empty, deployments from other branches will be preview environments"

YML

```
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Static Web App: '
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/my-portal'
    app_location: /
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: false
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'token'
    production_branch: develop
```

When running on branch refs/pull/1028/merge - the deployment still happens on production and a release environment is not created.

Is there a different way to configure this behaviour in Azure Devops, or does it simply not work?

Answer (score 0):

From `AzureStaticWebApp@0` Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-static-web-app-v0?view=azure-pipelines

> `deployment_environment` - Deployment Environment string.
>
> Environment to deploy to. Leave blank for production environment.
> Takes precedence over Production Branch.

Add `deployment_environment`, for example DEV:

```yaml
#yml
...
deployment_environment: DEV # string. Deployment Environment. 
...
```

Comment: The trick is that according to documentation you should be able to tell it what the production environment is, then it should treat all other branches as "not production" and essentially create a selection of dynamically named feature environments. 

By specifically naming deployment environment I am essentially limiting myself to one environment, but more importantly I have to create two release tasks, one for production and one for PR builds that are equal except for that setting.